# Can I adopt existing DOM elements into React component render output?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

How can I insert an existing DOM object into the rendered output from a React component?

Here's a noddy example of what I'm trying to do:

```
const template_text = `
  <svg>
    <g id="layer1">
      <circle x="0" y="0" r="10"/>
    </g>
  </svg>
`;

class MyComponent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.names = props.names;
    this.template = new DOMParser().parseFromString(template_text, "image/svg+xml");
  }

  render() {
    return (<g> {
      this.names.forEach(
        () =>
          this.template.documentElement
            .querySelector("g#layer1")
            .cloneNode(true)
      );
    } </g>);
  }
}
```

This sort of thing fails with `Objects are not valid as a React child (found: [object SVGGElement]). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.`

Is there a way to adopt DOM elements into React output?

Obviously for the example above I could just output the SVG content literally in the `render()` function but more generally the template is user-supplied.

Comment: Use [`__dangerouslySetInnerHtml`](https://react.dev/reference/react-dom/components/common#dangerously-setting-the-inner-html) but that’s only if you know what you’re inserting is safe and sanitized. User provided template shouldn’t be inserted as-is without any kind of sanity checks.

Comment: Care to post this as an answer, so I can accept it?

Comment: Consider that done :)

Comment: @Terry and accepted.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`__dangerouslySetInnerHtml`](https://react.dev/reference/react-dom/components/common#common-props) but that’s only if you know what you’re inserting is safe and sanitized. User provided template shouldn’t be inserted as-is without any kind of sanity checks.

Comment: Thanks.  The template is not user-provided as such, more developer-skinnable; I'm happy with the risk.